Always Rotate Cube Forward Relative to Observer
I want to rotate a cube forward relative to the camera (observer);
In psuedo-code:
rotateCubeForward(backward){
rotation.x += 90degress * backward;
}

rotateCubeForward(1)
rotateCubeForward(-1)

And that works well. But if I incorporate Z rotation things get complicated.
... include rotateCubeForward
rotateCubeRight(backward){
rotation.z += 90degress * backward;
}

rotateCubeForward(1)
rotateCubeRight(1)

This Spins the cube rather than tipping it forward and then tipping it right reletive the the camera.
I understand why its turning on its local axis. Hopefully this makes sense. Even a starting point would be great
Tried case specific code for what seems like 24 different states a cube can be in if rotated 90degrees at a time on x, y, z. but this got confusing quick. I almost had it, then 3-4 cases would be backwards which would turn into a game of whack a mole.
